# Query a WordPress page by its title (which has a parent page)

Tags: query-posts

I have created a wordpress query which takes the entire content from 1 particular page using the its title

So far i have the following:

```
<?php
query_posts('pagename=features');
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h3 class="center">No Section available</h3>
<p class="center"><?php _e("No Section available"); ?></p>
<?php endif;
//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The main issue is that there is numerous pages which care called 'features' but they all have different parents. Is it possible to do this via parent somehow?

For example, here is my hierarchical page structure:

products > designgo silver > features
products > designgo silver > screenshots
products > designgo silver > benefits

products > designgo gold > features
products > designgo gold > screenshots
products > designgo gold > benefits

products > designgo platinum > features
products > designgo platinum > screenshots
products > designgo platinum > benefits

If i could do something like:

```
<?php
query_posts('pagename=features&parent=designgosilver');
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
```

that would be perfect,

can anyone give us a pointer?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there—but **please**, use `WP_Query`.

```
$args = array(
    'pagename' => 'features',
    'post_parent' => PARENT-PAGE-ID-HERE,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    $query->the_post();

    // ...

    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

**// EDIT:**
If you don't want to or cannot use the parent page's ID, you can access it by its title, for instance like so:

```
    'post_parent' => ($parent = get_page_by_title('Designgo Silver')) ? $parent->ID : 0,
```

Comment: WP_QUERY also allows you to write something like this WP_Query('pagename=designgogold/features') - not sure if that's available in query_posts.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. That seems absolutely perfect but its not working exactly. Am i doing something wrong here:       <?php
$args = array('pagename' => 'features', 'post_parent' => 352);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        
<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h3 class="center">No Section available</h3>
<p class="center"><?php _e("No Section available"); ?></p>
<?php endif;
//Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly use the code I provided, but how does this not work? I just tested this, again, and I'm able to query a page by its slug **and** its parent. Don't you have any pages? Do you get not just the one you would like?

Comment: Hi, i have completed it using the code you provided & all seems to work perfectly now. I also have been able to query using WP_Query('pagename=designgogold/features') which is just what a i needed!! Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Alright, could you then please mark this answer as accepted. Otherwise your question will haunt the site from time to time... ;)